# how to convert 4x4 grid image to coordinates in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I need to generate an intersection matrix from the following image:
[image: sample image]

this image is a maze 4x4 grid board with some red and blue dots located randomly and the image will be taken from a mini-drone, I need to be able to find the location of red and blue dots to provide this information to a line follower that needs to pass through the blue dots avoiding the red ones.

I already applied some filters to this image to generate the contour but I don't know how to convert this to coordinates.
Here is what I did:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import random

original = cv2.imread('laberinto.jpg',1)
img = cv2.resize(original, (600,600), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
# cv2.imshow("Original",img)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3),0)

thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, 
cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 205, 1)
# cv2.imshow("Binary",thresh)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print(len(contours))

filtered = []
for c in contours:
   if cv2.contourArea(c) < 1000:continue
   filtered.append(c)

print(len(filtered))

objects = np.zeros([img.shape[0],img.shape[1],3], 'uint8')
for c in filtered:
  col = (random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255))
  cv2.drawContours(objects,[c], -1, col, -1)
  area = cv2.contourArea(c)
  p = cv2.arcLength(c,True)
  print(area,p)

cv2.imshow("Contours",objects) 

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

result:
[image: sample contour]